# how to retain dynamically created html elements and its data/values after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page where I dynamically add new elements (such as input and buttons) on the page using javascript (using createElement) on the click of a button. I then enter some values into those elements. But on refreshing the page I find that all the newly created html elements are removed from the page along with its associated data.

Also the elements are removed when I go to another page and return back to the original page.

Can anyone please suggest me a way to prevent this from happening.

I checked online and found some methods using cookies and ajax. But the thing here is the number of elements are not fixed so I can't apply those methods.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about persistent variables here. You can do it 3 ways, 2 of which you've already discarded.

- 1) Pulling data with AJAX from the server storage.
- 2) Saving data dynamically inside cookies and pulling it from there.
- 3) Using a browser's localStorage.

I can't really understand why the number of elements needs to be fixed in your case, it doesn't really matter if it is or not. You can save data, discard it when not needed and make a new one.

Edit:

I get it. Personally, I'd use localStorage for that purpose (unless there's some sensitive data included, e.g. bank account info and similar stuff).

On page load where you'd have your form shown, you immediately invoke a method for getting an existing data object inside localStorage, e.g. `localStorage.getItem(data)`.

If it's not existent, you bind `.submit()` form event so that it takes all the form's data with `.serialize()` or some other method, 
save that data (`localStorage.setItem(data, dataObject)`) inside localStorage and pull it again on the next page. If the user returns, you'll pull the data again the same way.

When user is finally done with data, you simply remove it (`localStorage.removeItem(data))`.

One more edit:
This won't work if you're dynamically adding (like you do) elements to the page. It could theoretically work if you're able to somehow store the created elements itself inside localStorage, convert them and add them again to the page (as localStorage and cookies can only keep strings). Never tried that, but in any case, you'd need to make your own element and data parser methods.

Comment: i'm creating a form with variable number of inputs. Upon submitting the form is previewed to the user. If the user needs to edit the form again he can go back and do the same. But when he goes back he should be abel to find the form as he left it. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say. Please suggest a better way if any.